# Find the PHP/HTML file containing DIV container shown in FireBug

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm editing an existing template in Joomla and I need to change the menu icons text. In Joomla Administrator, I cannot find the place where I can do this. So, in FireBug I found DIV container that I was searching for. But if I change the text in FireBug, my changes are obviously not saved. Now very basic question is: how can I know the name of PHP or HTML file, where this DIV container is located? Or how can I save my changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FireBug will only change web browsers content, it will not affect files on the server. If you know DIV's id you can search for files with this string on the server. To save changes - edit file and save - but on the server.

Comment: Thx. How do I search DIV string on server (localhost)? Sorry for such a basic question.

Comment: It depends from operating system, you can use varius tools (I like to do it with mc). On linux you can use ` grep -r "string i want to find"  path`

Comment: ack-grep is another great tool for full text search

Comment: btw you should accept the ansver and vote up would be nice :)

Comment: You can try directly from IDE (Netbeans or Eclipse) or follow this tutorial http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/in-windows-7-i-want-to-search-for-all-files/aadfe1f1-4a33-406b-8e72-bb920efa4f30

Answer (score 1):

I use TestWrangler app (I'm on a mac) - open blank TW, click on Search, browse to target a folder to search through. I always search through a copy of my website folders on my hard drive rather than live site files. Search for the text string you're wanting to find which file contains it. Give TW a few seconds or more and it will tell you exactly which file contains the string.
http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/

Answer (score 0):

When you right click on an HTML element and select "Inspect with firebug", on the right hand side of the firebug screen you will see the styles applied to that element, and where it says the line number, if you just hover your mouse over it it will show you the exact location of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use a file search tool, it is included in most IDE's, if your editor doesn't have such a feature try a file grep tools like wingrep (http://www.wingrep.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I'd share this as a possible 'answer' as well.

there is a joomla extension that enables you to search through your source code within joomla itself.

Here is the link:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/miscellaneous/development/22858

I'm sure it will come in handy instead of going through the hassle of a complex setup on localhost.